# Advanced searching in c# using multple dropdownlist

Tags: c#, database, advanced-search, advanced-filter

Hi I am into a homefinder project that should have an advanced search filter. It should have 3 dropdownlist from where the user can select rent amount, location, and gender type or the user can also Not select any bcause it has default value "ALL" which leads to showing all the houses stored n the database but if the user selects one or two values from the dropdownlist with the other default value as "ALL", or all the three has values, it should lead to the union of them. I tried using if statements

```
If (combobox1.text == "ALL" && combobox2.text == "ALL" && combobox3.text == "ALL")
{
 // shows all the homes
}
else if ( combobox1.text != "ALL" && combobox2.text == "ALL" && combobox3.text == "ALL")
{
 // say combobox1 is rent amount, shows all the homes having that rent amount
}

else if (combobox1.text == "ALL" && combobox2.text != "ALL" && combobox3.text == "ALL")
{
   // say combobox2 is gender type shows all the homes having that        gender category
   if (combox2.text == "Female")
     // all homes w "female"
   else
     // all homes w male
}

else if ( combobox1.text == "ALL" && combobox2.text == "ALL" && combobox3.text != "ALL")
{
// say combobox3 is location, shows all homes in that location
}

else if ( combobox1.text != "ALL" && combobox2.text != "ALL" && combobox3.text != "ALL")
{
}
else if ( combobox1.text != "ALL" && combobox2.text != "ALL" &&   combobox3.text == "ALL")
{
}
```

and so on, this is the code I have thought so far :l  how can I make the intersection of them. Like if I choose 500 under rentamount and 1st Street under location, how can I find the homes with 500 as rent amount that is located in the 1st Street?

And by the way, i already know how to show homes. My worry is just on how to find the intersections of the items in the dropdownlist.

Any help from you is appreaciated. Thank you

Comment: are you running your search against Sql Server..? if so then write a simple method that after you click the search button it goes into that event and then you can pass the values of the 3 boxes to a stored procedure creating a simple select based on the `IS NULL` check this is actually easier than you may think.. and in the Stored procedure or code you would use case when statement or if conditions to handle the `ALL` key word. also look up how to use the `LIKE` key word and understand the SQL WILDCARDS % %` and how to use them

Comment: Ok, I will work on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you are doing your data access, but this would be much easier and cleaner with Linq. Suppose you were using Linq2SQL or Entity Framework, and had a tables named Homes in your database, then if you had access to the EF context in a variable named `ctx` you could do something like this (Warning: Air code, and I renamed your combobox1 to something more meaningful)...

```
var homes = ctx.Homes;
if (cmbRentAmount.Text != "All") {
  homes = homes.Where(h => h.RentAmount == cmbRentAmount.Text);
}
// Similar for the other two combos
// ...
// Now we enumerate the query, which does the actual database access
var homesList = homes.ToList();
```

Note that the `homes` variable in the first line is an unenumerated query, meaning that L2S/EF doesn't actually query the database yet. You go through your three combos, modifying the query if the user selected something. When you enumerate `homes`, it will execute the query, and give you the results you want.

Comment: Hmm, Im still new to database but I will work on and consider that. Thank you.